# How to produce summary statistics table

Tags: stata

I would like to produce a summary statistics table looking like the one below:

```
       Female    Male
p1
p10
p50 
p99
```

However, with `estpost` and `esttab`, I can only produce a table like the following:

```
        (1)         (2)
      p1/p10/p5~99  p1/p10/p5~99
       -3.756124    -4.159476
        1.009338    -1.210738
        .3221763    .2945236
        .8658271    .8658271
        .9871135    .9871135
```

The code i am using is the following:

```
estpost summarize math_std if female == 1 , detail
eststo  female

estpost summarize math_std if female == 0 , detail
eststo  male

esttab female male , cells(p1 p10 p50 p95 p99) noobs
```

How can I put the column labels in the desired place?

Comment: I think you can't. On the left only variables are listed. You have 5 different statistics and these are listed as expected. Perhaps you should try the _community-contributed_ command `tabout`.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Thanks. I will  take a look at tabout package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution relying on the creation of a matrix with the relevant results:

```
sysuse auto, clear

quietly summarize price if foreign == 1 , detail
matrix foreign = r(p1) \ r(p10) \ r(p50) \ r(p95) \ r(p99)

quietly summarize price if foreign == 0 , detail
matrix domestic = r(p1) \ r(p10) \ r(p50) \ r(p95) \ r(p99)

matrix both = foreign , domestic
matrix rownames both = p1 p10 p50 p95 p99
matrix colnames both = foreign domestic

esttab matrix(both), mlabels(none)

--------------------------------------            
                  foreign     domestic
--------------------------------------
p1                   3748         3291
p10                  3895         3955
p50                  5759       4782.5
p95                 11995        13594
p99                 12990        15906
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the matrix solution.

Comment: For the same results in different layout, consider something like `tabstat price, by(foreign) s(p1 p10 p50 p90 p99)`

Comment: @NickCox i know right? If am ever to get that silver/gold badges you ought to give me some head-start when new questions are asked haha.

Comment: @NickCox a somewhat similar output to what you suggest using `esttab` is the following: `esttab foreign domestic, cells("p1 p10 p50 p95 p99") noobs`. There are so many commands to tabulate results now that it is getting quite difficult to keep track of all of them.

Comment: Indeed. It's easiest sometimes to write your own tabulation command, which I have done a few times.